# Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have an application lock for pessimistic concurrency and generate code in Asp.Net Mvc.

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
{
      using (var context = new Context())
      {
           var submitedEntity = context.Entities.Add(entity);
           context.SaveChanges();
           context.Entry(submitedEntity).Reload();
           code = submitedEntity.Code;

           scope.Complete();
      }
}
```

And generate code in SQL Server Trigger

```
Create  Trigger     [dbo].[OnInsertEntity]
On  [dbo].[TableName]
After   Insert
As
Begin
Begin   Transaction
    Declare @ID     BigInt,
        @LastCode   Int,
        @Length     Int,
        @Code       nChar(5)

Select  @ID     = ID
    From    Inserted

Select  @LastCode   = Max(Convert(Int, Code))
    From    [TableName]
    With    (TABLOCKX, HOLDLOCK)

If  @@RowCount      = 0
    Set @LastCode   = 0

Waitfor Delay '00:00:05'

Select  @Length     = Max_Length
    From    Sys.Columns
    Where   Name        = N'Code'   And
        [Object_ID] = Object_ID('[TableName]')

Select  @LastCode   = @LastCode + 1,
    @Code       = Replicate('0', @Length - Len(@LastCode)) + Convert(nChar, @LastCode)


Update  [TableName]
    Set Code    = @Code
    Where   ID  = @ID
Commit  Transaction
End
```

Error at:

```
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
```

> Transaction (Process ID) was deadlocked on lock resources with another 
>   process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

What is the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: OUCH, tablockx + waitfor delay in a trigger.

Comment: In addition to that you have a serious flaw in your logic, the inserted & deleted tables in SQL Server can (and will) contain more than one row when the insert / update is done for multiple rows

Comment: Waitfor Delay '00:00:05' It's for test pessimistic concurrency

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, it looks like you're just trying to update a running number to each row and it's actually a nchar field that contains leading zeros.

Using triggers with exclusive lock on the whole table etc. sounds like a bad idea. I would rather recommend you to use identity field in the table. If you really need to have a leading zeros, I would just add a computed column to the table that uses the identity field for the numbering.